# Jetpack Compose update UI based on changes in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to perform generic business logic and DB interaction from a ViewModel class and update the UI after that is complete. However, updating the value of the mutable does not result in changes in the UI.

Here is the View:

```
class LoginView() {
    @Composable
    fun Login(navController: NavHostController, appDB: AppDatabase){
        val loginVM = LoginVM()
        val isLoggedIn = remember { loginVM.loggedIn }

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text("Login Screen")
            if(isLoggedIn){
                Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("addUser") }) { Text("Add User") }
            }else{
                var studyPIN by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                TextField(
                    value = studyPIN,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = { newText ->
                        studyPIN = newText
                    },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
                )
                Button(onClick = { loginVM.Login(appDB, studyPIN.text) }) { Text("Login") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
class LoginVM: ViewModel() {
    var loggedIn by mutableStateOf(false)

    fun Login(appDB: AppDatabase, studyPIN: String){
        //Business logic goes here
        loggedIn = true
    }
}
```

Update: Here is the combined code that works. I have a top layer NavHost that handles passing in VMs.

```
class LoginView() {

    @Composable
    fun Login(navController: NavHostController, appDB: AppDatabase, loginVM: LoginVM){
        val uiState by loginVM.uiState.collectAsState()

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text("Login Screen")
            if(uiState.isLoggedIn){
                Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("addUser") }) { Text("Add User") }
            }else{
                var studyPIN by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                TextField(
                    value = studyPIN,
                    singleLine = true,
                    onValueChange = { newText ->
                        studyPIN = newText
                    },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
                )
                Button(onClick = { loginVM.Login(appDB, studyPIN.text) }) { Text("Login") }
            }
        }
    }
}

class LoginVM: ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(LoginUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<LoginUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun Login(appDB: AppDatabase, studyPIN: String) = viewModelScope.launch{
        //Business logic goes here
        _uiState.value = LoginUiState(true)
    }
}

data class LoginUiState(val isLoggedIn:Boolean = false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You view model should host a StateFlow, which your View consumes.  Here is how my VM's usually expose state.

```
private val _viewState = MutableStateFlow<YourState>(YourState())
val viewState: StateFlow<YourState> = _viewState
```

You update the state simply by setting the value property on the _viewState like this:

```
_viewState.value = YourState(<values>)
```

The view then consumes the state in a lifecycle aware fashion, like so:

```
val state = viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
```

Here is a code lab from google that well help you understand better.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new viewmodel instance in every recomposition. You can use your viewModel like below.

```
viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
```

You need to implement `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1` to use `viewModel()` function or you can simply use `hiltViewModel()` check for more https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries

If you want to use `mutableState()` in your viewmodel you dont need to remember it in composable function you can use it like below but i highly suggest you to use `stateFlow`

```
class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {

var loggedIn = mutableStateOf(false)

}

@Composable
fun Login(navController: NavHostController, appDB: AppDatabase){
    val viewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel()
    val isLoggedIn = viewModel.loggedIn
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's for sure why it was immediately resetting the view.

Comment: is there any reason to use composable inside a class btw ? @M.Boyce